# I have installed Brave, but cannot find the app

Tags: software-installation, snap

I am using this tutorial: https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/blob/master/docs/linuxInstall.md and following this command because I have Ubuntu 16.04 `snap install brave --beta`. It installed successfully but I cannot find the app. I think it happens most of the time. Where can I find it or create the shorcut of the app?

Comment: What happens if you do `snap run brave`?

Comment: @muru there is a shortcut of Brave after I restart my laptop. It solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Snap installed applications not showing on launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150609/snap-installed-applications-not-showing-on-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and only typed "brave" on the *command-line* and app was launched. Then I locked it to the launcher.
however I expect after restarting to find the shortcut.