# Snap installed applications not showing on launcher

Tags: gnome, snap, gtk3

After installing applications using Snap (e.g: slack, chromium browser) they not appear in gnome launcher. Not able to run them using `[gtk-launch][1]` neither.

`.desktop` files exist in */var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications* but somehow the are not recognized.

For instance, for Slack application, the .desktop file content is:

```
➜  cat /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/slack_slack.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
X-SnapInstanceName=slack
Name=Slack
Comment=Slack Desktop
GenericName=Slack Client for Linux
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/slack_slack.desktop /snap/bin/slack %U
Icon=/snap/slack/14/usr/share/pixmaps/slack.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;InstantMessaging;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/slack;
```

And, when trying to launch from the command line:

```
➜  gtk-launch slack_slack
gtk-launch: no such application slack_slack
```

When I execute `/snap/bin/slack` the application works fine.

Comment: Why don't you try running it from the terminal and put the errors in here

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `/var/lib/snapd/desktop` is not in `XDG_DATA_DIRS`.
You can add it by putting

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS="${XDG_DATA_DIRS}:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"
```

or (if `/etc/profile.d/snapd.sh` exists in your system)

```
source /etc/profile.d/snapd.sh
```

in `~/.profile` or in `~/.gnomerc`.
Of course you can also copy or symlink snapd `*.desktop` files from `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` to one of the paths in `XDG_DATA_DIRS` or even to `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Kali